# How to recursively invoke methods like: q[0].from(q[1].from(q[2].from(q[3]))) when q size is unknown?

Tags: ruby, recursion

How to recursively invoke methods like: `q[0].from(q[1].from(q[2].from(q[3])))`
in Ruby when q size is unknown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inject` for this:

```
q.reverse_each.inject do |acc, value|
  value.from(acc)
end
```

The reverse is needed to get things in the right order. The first time the block is invoked `acc` is the last element from `q`, `q[3]` in your example and value is `q[2]`. On the next iteration, value is `q[1]` and `acc` is the result from the previous block (`q[2].from(q[3])`) so it calculates

```
q[1].from(q[2].from(q[3]))
```

And so on